# Laravel 5: Redirecting woes

Tags: laravel

This line works in routes.php:

```
Route::get('faq', 'HomeController@faq');
```

So I comment it out and try this: Doesn't work when the user is logged in. It will not redirect into the controller action that works in the aforementioned code:

```
Route::get('faq', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@faq');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Error:

```
New exception in xxxx.xx
InvalidArgumentException · GET /faq
Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@faq not defined.
```

But the controller and method are clearly there. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you try putting "/" before faq. Something like Route::get('/faq').

Comment: don't check for authentication in your Route. instead use middlewares for your controller action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to route something within a route definition itself. That is not how it works.

There are a few ways you could do what you want to achieve. There are pros/cons to each - but they would all work.

Generally the best way is to use some [Auth middleware on your route](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware). Laravel 5 [includes this out of the box](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-routing):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('faq', 'HomeController@faq');
});
```

So the user must be logged in to access the FAQ.

Another option is to do [Controller Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware):

```
Route::get('faq', 'HomeController@faq');
```

*then in your HomeController*:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['faq']]);
    }

    public function faq()
    {    
        // Only logged in users can see this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked very well. (Route::group) approach